# ::SharedPtr vs std::shared_ptr<>

Tags: ros, ros2, shared-ptr

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Please bear with me, I haven´t been programming since 2006, and it turns out that learning both c++11/c++17 and ROS2 has a bit of a steep learning curve. ;-)

After reading the relevant chapters at learncpp.com, I think I have an adequate understanding of std::shared_ptr, weak_ptr and unique_ptr.

However, going back to the ROS2 tutorials, I see that often an alias is defined:

```
using something::SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<something>
```

For instance, in the publisher tutorial, the publisher is declared as follows:

```
rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr publisher_;
```

which (I think) is fully equivalent to:

```
std::shared_ptr<clcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>> publisher_;
```

I find this rather confusing, even more so since it is not general. For instance, in the TF2 TransformBroadcaster tutorial, the broadcaster must be declared as follows:

```
std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster> tf_static_broadcaster_;
```

since the ::SharedPtr alias is not defined:

```
tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster::SharedPtr tf_static_broadcaster_;
// Not ok: "class tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster has no member SharedPtr"
```

So: is there any specific reason (other than it being 6 characters less) to give preference to the `::SharedPtr` way of declaring, or is it ok to stick to using `std::shared_ptr<...>`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409760/::sharedptr-vs-std::shared_ptr%3C%3E/) by [jrtg](https://answers.ros.org/users/124778/jrtg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 145 on 2022-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is certainly fine to use `std::shared_ptr<>` for new code.

The SharedPtr alias is a legacy from the ros1 days. `std::shared_ptr<>` is a relatively recent addition to the c++ standard, and before that the SharedPtr defined by ros was a type alias to a boost library shared pointer class. It saved a lot more typing back then *and* made it clearer what the code was doing.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2